# Remove special character from multiple file names in folder in python

Tags: python

I am trying to remove special character(-) from multiple files in  folder.

Example:

Filenames :

1. -name1.xml
2. -name2.xml
3. -name3.xml

Rename To:

1. name1.xml
2. name2.xml
3. name3.xml

My Code :

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir(Folder):
    os.rename(Folder+'/'+filename, Folder + '/' + Filename.replace("-","" )
```

but Unfortunately it appears to do nothing.

How do I do this properly?

Comment: `Filename` should be `filename`. Python is case-sensitive.

Comment: Other than that, the code should work. But it's best to use `os.path.join()` instead of string concatenation.

Comment: needs closing bracket

Comment: Hi @Barmar - It's working now. Thanks Barmar!

Answer (score 0):

In the code below, you can simply use the replace function to get your desired output. Let me know if this works and/or helps!

```
import os

# I named my folder containing .XML files "Test"
Folder = 'Test/'

for filename in os.listdir(Folder):
    os.rename(Folder + filename, Folder + filename.replace('-',''))
```

Outputs:

```
name1.xml
name2.xml
name3.xml
```

Answer (score -1):

I am a big fan of using [Pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) for problems like this.

Given (on Unix but should work on all OSs):

```
% ls -1
-name1.xml
-name2.xml
-name3.xml
name-4.xml
```

You can do:

```
from pathlib import Path 

p=Path(Folder)

for fn in p.glob("-*.xml"):
    fn.replace(fn.with_name(str(fn.name).replace('-','')))
```

Result:

```
% ls -1
name-4.xml
name1.xml
name2.xml
name3.xml
```

The glob `-*.xml` only will find files that start with `-` so the file `name-4.xml` is unchanged.

Pathlib (as written here) will also work the same regardless of the path separator on different OSs.

Comment: Hi dawg - It's working.